# CopyMemory with CObject

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, ipc, visual-c++-6

I am trying to use Shared Memory to communicate between 2 processes, and I want to transfer a CObject object.

I have

```
class CMyObject : public CObject  
{
public:
CMyObject();
virtual ~CMyObject();

public:
int m_nId;
CString m_sData;
};
```

and this object, I intend to send via IPC:

```
if(NULL == m_pMyObject)
{
    m_pMyObject = new CMyObject;
    m_pMyObject->m_nId = 24;
    m_pMyObject->m_sData = sBuffer;
}
```

and

```
HANDLE hMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, lpszMappingName);
LPVOID lpData = MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(CMyObject));
if(NULL != lpData)
    CopyMemory(lpData, m_pMyObject, sizeof(CMyObject));
```

seems to work.

But when I am trying to read CMyObject data in second process:

```
HANDLE hMapping = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, 0, pszMappingName);
CMyObject* lpData = (CMyObject*)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, sizeof(CMyObject));
if(NULL != lpData)
    TRACE(_T("%s"), lpData->m_sData);
```

sometime is crashing, something get nothing .... can you get me a little help, please ?
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot transfer a `CString` from one process to another because `CString` uses an internal pointer that doesn't mean the same thing in two different address spaces. You should transfer a simple `struct` instead containing only native types, in your case an `int` and an array of `char`. E.g: `struct MyObject {int m_nId; int strlen; char m_sData[1]}`.

Comment: Thank you for your attention ... CMyObject is just for testing purpose ... in fact, I want to transfer a CMemFile object, which is derived from CObject as well.

Comment: The problem is exactly the same. CMemFile contains probably pointers too.

Comment: You need to "translate" your object to some memory agnostic representation in the sender process and retranslate it to an object in the receiver process. This is called "marshalling".

Comment: I have searched on google what you said, but I didn't found something that could help me ... could you elaborate a little bit ? Thank you.

Comment: In fact, I am using that CMemMapFile: http://www.naughter.com/memmap.html ... but I haven't disk file, only CMemFile ... but what if I want to send an complex CObject derivate object ?

Comment: If you wish to transfer complex data from one process to another, the common solution is *serialization*, usually over a stream-like IPC channel (such as a pipe). `CObject` has built-in serialization support, that needs to be extended for derived classes.

Comment: You mean, serialization on disk/registry ?

Comment: Because then, I could use CFile instead of CMemFile, but requesting say that I should use CMemFile, unserialized (unsaved).

Comment: @flaviu2 maybe yolu should tell us what actuel problem you are trying to solve. It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Using shared memory, I want to transfer a CMemFile from an process to another ... code sample from above illustrate my trials.

Comment: I succeeded to transfer a CString, but CMemFile could me anything else than strings ...

Comment: Serialization is the process of converting structured data into a one-dimensional stream of octets. Physical files are a common target for serialization, but not the only ones. Serialization is used to store complex data in DB's, communicate with servers, or to transfer data between processes. So no, I'm not suggesting to serialize data to a physical file. I explicitly named *"pipes"* as a viable transport. Regardless, sharing a memory-mapped file between processes is as easy as mapping the same file into another process.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I will try to change class CMyObject into struct SMyObject, and try to send it from an process to another ... I will come back with news. Kindly thank you.

Comment: @flaviu2 be aware that your struct cannot contain any pointers, or instances of classes that use pointers (especially CString and most of other MFC as well.)

Comment: @flaviu2 just to trigger some thinking: using the `CMyObject` class in your question: what do you think happens when you write your object like this `fwrite (m_pMyObject, sizeof(CMyObject), 1, somestream);` and you read it later with `fread`?

Comment: @llnspectable: I have tried to serialize CMemFile through CArchive ... I don't think it's possible: at CArchive::Close, I get assert error: m_pFile (type of CMemFile) must has filename ... ! And my CMemFile, (m_pFile) has not ! What should I do ?